# YouTube Retrieve a Refresh Token?

Tags: ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I am sending a delete request to the youtube api but I am receiving a 401 error (unauthorized). I'm not sure why. My key is set properly, I am able to access the analytics of the youtube channel. This is my code that fires on a button click

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        // must set api key
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+ thisUniqueID + '&key={<?php echo $oAuth2Key; ?>}',
    });
```

I've used alert to check that my auth key is set properly (shown below).

```
alert('<?php echo $oAuth2Key; ?>');
```

and I can see in the returned address with the error that the url is proper. What could be the issue?

---

It looks like I need a refresh token. This is straight out of the docs: The API will return an HTTP 401 response code (Unauthorized) if you submit a request to access a protected resource with an expired access token. The following section explains how to refresh an access token.

Is there an easy way to retrieve a refresh token at the same time that I send a delete request? If not is there an easy way to retrieve one with out the need for the client id/client secret etc.

I somehow have gotten a key for analytics, but when I go to delete a video the key is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Data API v3 instead.

Yes, you can do AJAX calls. Here's the [videos->delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete) call.

DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEO_ID&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: What is the API key? Youtube API? Also what about all the code up above? Is that all relevant only to v2?

Comment: I tried using the google api key with youtube data api v3 and youtube analytics api turned on, but I am receiving an 401 unauthorized user error. Am I using the wrong key?

Seems the youtube api console is down at the moment.

Comment: Is this the api key that I am supposed to be using??
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register

The youtube site seems to be down and has been all day, but I am trying to get a key from there to see if that will work instead -
https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html

Comment: That would work, you can also try it from API explorer here after signing in  https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.delete

Comment: I keep hitting a 401 (Unauthorized) error. I have my auth key set properly because I am able to hit the analytics with it. Why wouldn't I be able to delete with the same key?

This is what I get
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=jsxbVtoWhos&key={my-api-key-here}`

-- Note I also tried without the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You find the documentation for using authorization at:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

You use the API key for access to public data !

Since you want to delete a video, you must use the access_token. An access_token is valid for a short time (1 hour). You can get a new one by using your refresh_token to request another one.
Store a refresh_token since it is valid until it gets revoked.

BTW.

```
Maybe use client.js, to handle the authorization for your requests ?
For JS, by adding:

 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

The general documentation is at:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

An code example for YouTube is at:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

For reference of the video delete method see:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#videos

The listed methods are: insert, list, delete, update , rate and getRating.

The delete method might be (This is NOT tested with a valid videoID):

```
var requestOptions = {
  id: '012345678901',                    // replace VIDEOID
  part: 'id'
```

};

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.delete (requestOptions);

request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log("RESPONSE: " + response);
});
```

The response using a non-existing videoId is:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": -32500,
   "message": "Video not found",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "youtube.video",
     "reason": "videoNotFound",
     "message": "Video not found",
     "locationType": "parameter",
     "location": "id"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for that code snippet. That actually helps a lot. This is how I've gone about getting authorization for my analytics. But just including the script wont work, I imagine you need to 'catch' the token and then put it to use. I've called it in via ajax, and it successfully loads.

Comment: Yes, there should be links somewhere in the documentation to examples, that show you how to use it. I will see if i can add something more.

Comment: Where is the key stored inside of the YouTube example? I can authenticate etc, but I am not able to retrieve and pass the stored access token to the delete request. If I can extract the key when I authenticate through analytics, I can pass that to my ajax delete request

Comment: I have not looked at that. I guess it is stored in a cookie on your computer. I think it uses the same cookie when you login on youtube.com. Your supposed to use the provided methods. Not sure if there is a method that let you extract the tokens.

Comment: Is there a simple way to access this cookie? Right now I am receiving the access token through the URL, but it is not stored anywhere so I am not able to make requests to the API, once I direct away from the page the access token is removed from the URL and I need to resubmit to retrieve a new one

Comment: I don't think so. But you should be able the capture the url with the token. I add above, what i think the delete method is for a video, since it is mentioned in the documentation. Have not tried the code myself.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need to use the newly retrieved 'access token' to delete my videos. Not my google api client id, or simple API key, right?

I've been attempting to use the key that was provided, but I still receive the 401 error (unauthorized). I am able to request the token by directing to the google screen to grant access, then I am redirected to my page where the access token is in the header. But thats as far as I get =/

Comment: Yes, you need a fresh access_token; it will normally be valid for 1 hour. Look for a way to capture it from the url. Then try a request, like: DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=jsxbVtoWhos&access_token=ACCESTOKEN  (Should be somewhere in the documentation.)

Comment: I think it also needs "&part=id" appended to the URL.